# Saving comments on request

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, billing-address, onestepcheckout

In the checkout, I have a `select` from which the user should choose their address type (commercial or residential) and I want to save this as a comment in the request, however I do not know how I should do to achieve the same.

**`Select` Code:**

```
<div class="field info">
  <label for="comments" class="tipoEnd">Type of address:</label>
  <div class="input-box">
     <div class="styled-select" style="width: 90% !important;">
        <select class="required-entry" id="commentsEnd" name="commentsEnd" title="<?php echo $this->__('Type of address') ?>" class="validate-select onestep required-entry">
         <option>Select</option>
         <option value="residential">Residential</option>
         <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

**Note: I can already save comments in the request, which would be the "Benchmarks" field, from the following codes:**

**Code in file billing.phtml:**

```
<label for="comments"><?php echo $this->__('Reference: ') ?></label>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input style="width: 100% !important;" class="input-text required-entry" id="comments" name="comments" title="<?php echo $this->__('
Reference points:') ?>" />
  </div>
```

**Code in the Observer.php file in the onestepcheckout module:**

```
if (!empty($oscOrderData['comments'])) {

$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
/* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

$order->addStatusHistoryComment($oscOrderData['comments']);
$order->save();
}
```

**Note 2: If I use the same logic, putting the id of the `select` being `comments`, I have a problem because one overwrites the other. And if I duplicate this code in `Observer.php`, putting two of it, but changing the `id` putting for example `address` and in the `label` and the `input` put the `id` being `address`, the same problem occurs, one overwrites the other.**

Would it not be possible, for example, to concatenate the two so that they may be saved together?

Comment: Do you  using onepage checkout -out  and onestep checkout?

Comment: @AmitBera I'm using onestep checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is change the code contained in the Observer.php file to save the data from an `Array`. For this to happen, the fields in the `HTML` code must be changed as well.

**Updated `HTML` field code:**

```
      <label for="comments"><?php echo $this->__('Reference: ') ?></label>
      <div class="input-box">
          <input style="width: 100% !important;" class="input-text" id="comments_1" name="comments[]" title="<?php echo $this->__('
Reference points:') ?>" />
       </div>
    </div>

       <div class="field info">
        <label for="commentsEnd" class="tipoEnd">Type of address:</label>
        <div class="input-box">
           <div class="styled-select">
           <select id="comments_2" name="comments[]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Type of address') ?>" class="onestep">
              <option value="">Selecione</option>
              <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
              <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
           </select>
           </div>
        </div>
```

**Code updated in Observer.php file:**

```
if (!empty($oscOrderData['comments'])) {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

    // Force array type
    if(!is_array($oscOrderData['comments']))
        $oscOrderData['comments'] = array($oscOrderData['comments']);

    foreach($oscOrderData['comments'] as $comment) {
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment);
    }
    $order->save();
}
```